# How to make custom text use the Inline Translation tool in Magento Enterprise

Tags: php, magento, translation, customization, enterprise

I've created a piece of text in a Magento Template, and the inline translation tool is turned on and working fine, but when I visit the page with my custom text, it seems to ignore that it's translatable (no book icon and dotted red border).

So here's what I have (approx):

```
<div class="foo">
    <?php echo $this->__('My custom Text'); ?>
</div>
```

Which renders fine, and if I edit the relevant CSV file, it changes appropriately.

Is there any way to "add" this to the translation tool's eyeline?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: OK, apparently this works as a general thing, but some elements don't - one such problem is the Magento OnePage Checkout - First Name is not translatable inline, but Last name is.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OK, Managed to find the problem - so for anybody that wants to use the inline translation stuff, do:

```
<div class="foo">
    <span>
        <?php echo $this->__('My custom Text'); ?>
    </span>
</div>
```

There's a list of allowed translatable inline tags on line #87 of app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Translate/Inline.php ("_allowedTagsSimple"). Enabling divs here is madness itself, but wrapping in spans should be generally quite safe.

Comment: So that's how it works! I had wondered. I would +2 your post if I could.

Comment: Much appreciated @clockworkgeek, I'm sifting through the underbelly of Mage Core trying to figure out what's keeping it from the odd remaining tag I have untranslatable - apparently this doesn't work for everything. I've narrowed it down to the same file as mentioned above, line #384. If you comment out the check "if (!empty($trArr))" it will highlight absolutely everything I need, but with no content, so I'm missing something in the structure still. I'll post with anything further